# My code will not execute past the invalid function

Tags: python

The goal is to move between room using a dictionary to organize rooms.

I've tried everything I know the code works perfectly until an input send the code to the if else statement containing the invalid() function then the code is stuck in an infinate loop in the invalid() function no matter what is entered it never goes back to the beginning. any help is appreciated.

```
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }


def instruction():
    """Function to give instructions on how to play the game"""
    print('Welcome to Module 6 Milestone')
    print('Move commands are go North, go South, go East, go West')
    print('Typing exit will exit the game')
    print('Inputting directions will remind you of the move commands')
    print('Good luck may the odds be in your favor')


def invalid():
    """Function for if an invalid input is entered"""
    print('------------')
    print('Whoops invalid command, try again')
    print('------------')


def main():
    """Main function that runs the movement between rooms"""
    current_room = 'Great Hall'
    print('\nYou are starting in the', current_room)
    move = input('What will you do next?\n>').split()
    directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
    while True:
        if len(move) < 2:
            if 'exit' in move:
                print('\nThanks for playing!')
                break
            if 'instructions' in move:
                instruction()
                print('------------')
                print('\nYou are in the', current_room)
                move = input('\nWhat will you do next?\n>')
            else:
                invalid()
                print('You are still in the', current_room)
                move = input('What will you do next?\n>')
        if len(move) >= 2:
            if move[1] in directions:
                if move[1] in rooms[current_room]:
                    current_room = rooms[current_room][move[1]]
                    print('------------')
                    print('You have found the', current_room)
                    move = input('What will you do next?\n>').split()
                elif move[1] not in rooms[current_room]:
                    print('------------')
                    print('Oh no it seems to be a dead in')
                    print('You are still in the', current_room)
                    move = input('What will you do next?\n>').split()
            else:
                invalid()
                print('You are still in the', current_room)
                move = input('What will you do next?\n>')


instruction()
print('------------')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hint: after calling `invalid()`, you're not taking input in quite the same way that you do elsewhere. Can you see what you've forgotten?

Comment: Hint2: Since the `move` variable and its `len()` is what controls the flow and you're seeing behaviour that you do not expect in part of your code, a useful debugging tactic can be to print those values in your program after having taken the input to see what is happening differently than what you expect!

Comment: Tip: to avoid errors like this, try not to repeat yourself. Here, the line `move = ...` appears in multiple parts of the while loop. Instead you could first handle the current move. And only after going through all possibilities (instructions, invalid move, ...), ask for the next move (only once at the very end of the while loop).

Comment: thanks everyone I got it figured out with yalls help!